# scrape data from Instagram - errors while running Instascrape

Tags: python, scrape

I am trying to scrape post, and other information related to that post using instascrape. I am receiving an errors. So kindly help me out in this. If you know any other package that can do the same, kindly let me know.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from instascrape import Profile, scrape_posts
webdriver = Chrome("path/to/chromedriver.exe")

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.57",
    "cookie": "sessionid=PASTE_YOUR_SESSIONID_HERE;"
}
joe = Profile("joebiden")
joe.scrape(headers=headers)
```

**output:**

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python "JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)" occurs when we try to parse an invalid JSON string (e.g. single-quoted keys or values, or a trailing comma). Use the `ast.literal_eval()` method to solve the error.

Here is a way to go about it
[image: Image that explains your error]